# ADT Plugin "Loading data for Android X.X.X" every time XML files are opened

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I know there are some questions like this on stackOverflow, but i think they are old. 
I'm working with the latest versions of Android SDK Tols (24.3.2 rev) and ADT 23.0.6. This problem with eclipse, it seems fixed for ADT 22.6.3, but i dont want to downgrade my ADT version.

Anyone can help to fix this problem?.

My scenario:

- Eclipse Juno
- Jdk 1.7
- Android SDK Tools 24.3.2 rev
- ADT 23.0.6
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- 8GB ram

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm using the old Eclipse Bundle with sdk. If set Android Sdk Path to the sdk bundle, the problem appears but if i use SDK from [USER]/AppData/Android/sdk i works as espected. (AppData Android is generated by Android Studio).

My question is, what is the reason for that behavior?.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the version of your SDK and ADT. You can resolve installing Android Studio that is now the official IDE for Android Application development.
Here is a notice from developer.android.com:

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse is ending, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating to Android Studio.

[Android studio download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

[Android studio overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

try updating android sdk.

form adt bundle folder, open sdk.exe in administration mode.
then only update will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the because of the sdk tools. you are using a latest Android sdk and ADT 23.0.6. Ther might be some issue of that cause there will not be any update in ADT from now on. It is clearly stated on the developer.android.com.
So i suggest to move on to the Android studio where you will have all the updated plugin and codes.